# Ajax call restful WS is always getting error (fiddler gets the good response)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iis-7, wcf-rest

I have made Restfull WS in VS 2010 with two simple method (one GET, another POST). They look like:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
    {

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "createUser")]
    string createUser();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "loginUser/{email}/{password}")]
    string loginUser(string email, string password);

    }
```

Definition of these methods is simple:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {

 public string createUser()
        {
            return "Successful POST call !!! ";
        }

 public string loginUser(string email, string password)
        {
            return "Successful GET call !!! " + email + " - "+ password;
        }
  }
```

I have published this service to IIS and tested my method in browser (only loginUser (GET) method, cannot test createUser (POST) method by the browser) and method (loginUser ) work fine.
When I tried to call method by jQuery AJAX, I am always getting error call without any notification. I checked my fiddler and there are the right response.

My Ajax method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#button2").click(function(){

  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",                 
   url: "http://localhost/AutoOglasi/Service1.svc/loginUser/bole/bole",

   success: function (response) {
    alert("respons  "+response);
   },
       error: function (request, status, error) {
    alert(request.responseText+" -- " + status + " --- "+ error);
   }
     });                

});

});
```

I mozila firebug i section XML I get this:

XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{ba25ef4a-f215-486e-b965-e70714c5af31} Line Number 1, Column 1:
^

What I am doing wrong here, I just cannot figure out, because fiddler is giving me good response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.XmlResponseFormat` and what you return is not xml but a string. It expects the first character to be a < but its a S thats why its not finding an element at position 1

Comment: I have already tried that (to add contenttype:"text/xml"), and I tried again. Now I am getting:
                                                          "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost/AutoOglasi/Service1.svc/loginUser/bole/bole"

Comment: Always when I tried to add contentType (with json, xml or html), the same error appear (error above).
I think that I did not understand second part of your answer. 
In bout situation, (with ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml or not) error appears.

Comment: I think the servise gives xml by default if you do not add ResponseFormat.

For me it does not matter what kind of response I will get (xml, json, html), I just want to get something.

Comment: @Milos Is your Ajax method and webservice on the same server? Else you could be looking at a cross domain call.

Comment: @ Rick  No, my webservice and my Ajax were not on the same server. I tried to add my Application on the same server and now it is working.

Comment: Can I overcome that problem. I need to call that web service from different domain. I wanna make "PhoneGap" (mobile application based on Java Script) application which will use that webservice. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Milos I have a lot of experience with PhoneGap only not specifically with cross domain calls on it. But something I would suggest to make it easier, use JSONP, look at how to configure your webserver (with cross-domain-policy)

Comment: Just Google around a bit, its a lot easier when you know what your searching for;-) Could you please let me know when you find the answer, I'm quite interested

Comment: PhoneGap translates java script, html and css on something else (I do not exactly what) which is not java script and so on.   According it, we do not have "cross domain" problem. For me everything is working fine (POST and GET methods). In order to test application I needed to put both (service and application) on the same server, but with PhoneGap everything is ok.

Comment: So I can conclude from this that you have found an answer?

Comment: Yes, I found the answer thanks to you. If you need exact code for Ajax POST call or anything else, just let me know.